# How and when does a server-side rendered webpage update the page source?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Today I feel everything I know about SSR is wrong.

Let's take for example [NextJS'](https://nextjs.org/) website:

On the first load, I can see under Dev tools (Network) the HTML being fetched along with other assets.
If I navigate to any other page, I see some JSON files being loaded through fetch API under (XHR) tab, which contain the HTML strings for that page.

My understanding till now was that the page source doesn't update if data is populated using AJAX (what I believe is called client-side rendering), then how does Server side rendered data (even though fetched asynchronously) update the page source.

Isn't a reload necessary to update the page source?